# Why does Postman change saved API requests

Tags: postman

I'm using Postman to test API and like its GUI and ease of use. But some things it does are completely incomprehensible to me. Example: I save an API request to a collection. Sometime later I try to recall it and it has changed. Why?

Scenario: testing against ElasticSearch API

1. GET _cat/indices.
2. Save to collection ElasticSearch.
3. Send other ES API requests.
4. Delete an index: DELETE /index0
5. Recall saved _cat/indices
6. Instead DELETE /index0 is recalled. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman has tabs along the top, where each tab holds the data for a given request. When you edit the contents of a tab, you are editing the saved request as well. If you manually hit "save", the changes to the request are saved.

The way to avoid this would be to make sure that any time you are writing a new request and not intending to make it a change to an existing one, you do it in a new request tab (click the `+` button on the tab line), which you can then optionally save as a new named request.

Comment: Thank you. Kludgey work flow but at least I know the problem now.

Comment: I must be the stupidest guy in the world, but I cannot find a setting to turn off auto-save. Do you happen to know where it is?

Comment: Took a look. I can't find it, and it seems like autosave might **not** be a Postman feature (e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3466) implies it hasn't been implemented). There is an "Always ask when closing unsaved tabs" option - is it possible that rather than unintentionally over-writing, you're unintentionally not writing what you think you are?

Comment: Postman doesn't 'auto save' the changes. Each time you change anything in the request, you'll see an orange dot in the tab. You are either saving this with a keyboard shortcut or hitting the save button on the UI.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that you turned off the "Always ask when closing unsaved tabs" option in Settings -> General.  When this is off, it does not require you to hit Save, it will automatically save when the tab is closed.

Answer (score 0):

To Turn Off Autosave, do the following:

1. Go to Settings -> General
2. Turn On Always ask when closing unsaved tabs.
3. Open a saved request, then change something in the request.
4. Close the request tab. Postman will ask if you want to save the changes. There will be a checkbox "to always discard unsaved changes". Tick the checkbox.
5. Click on "Don't Save".